# Add 'whatever' to string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, ckeditor

I have a function in Javascript which replace a textarea with CKEDITOR.

```
document.getElementById("text").action=CKEDITOR.replace(
         'body_content',
         {toolbar : 'big',
          height : '450',
          enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR}
);
```

Now I'd like to replace 3 textareas with CKEDITOR on the same function. The 3 areas have name body_contentSOMETHING.

How can I write an expression to replace SOMETHING with whatever?

EDIT:
whatever is not defined. should be something like *.exe on windows file reseach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `body_content{{something}}` is an `id`, you can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to [select them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and loop:

```
var content_areas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea[id^="body_content"]');

for (var i = 0, l = content_areas.length; i < l; i++) {
    content_areas[i].action = CKEDITOR.replace(
         content_areas[i],
         {toolbar : 'big',
          height : '450',
          enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR}
    );
}
```

For compatibility with IE 8, you can use `textarea[id|="body_content"]` (`|=` vs `^=`), but this expects the value to be whole or followed by a `-`:

```
<textarea id="body_content-something"></textarea>
```

Or add a `class` to the elements to query by:

```
<textarea id="body_contentsomething" class="body_content"></textarea>
```

```
var content_areas = document.querySelectorAll('.body_content');

// ...
```

Also, without knowing what `document.getElementById("text")` is supposed to refer to, I'm not sure how to keep that in the snippets.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, *if* you're okay with using `querySelectorAll`. Since the OP's example and comments point to not being able to expect a hyphen being used, I used a manual DOM traversal approach. In the end, both do the same, this one is just more modern and a little shorter.

Comment: Thank you! This solution is perfect, the only problem is that I use `document.getElementById("text").action` because those `areas` are included on a `AJAX` reply. If I only post the standard CKEDITOR solution the JS is not executed.

Comment: You can access `content_areas[i].action` for the assignment just like I did in my answer.

Comment: @Perocat Well, what is `document.getElementById('text')`, exactly? I can only guess how to help with that without knowing more. Such as: Is it a `<form>`? If so, its `.action` can only hold the value from 1 `CKEDITOR.replace()`. So, does each `<textarea>` have its own `<form>`? How are the `<form>`s identified?

Comment: @IngoBürk Perfect, I used `content_areas[i].action` and works like a charm! It's a `<div>`: it was neccesary to run the `JS code`. Now I found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Based on an answer from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string) you can traverse the DOM like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4cFu/63/)):

```
function getElementsByIdStartsWith(selectorTag, prefix) {
    var items = [];
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(selectorTag);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].id.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) === 0) {
            items.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    return items;
}

var affectedElements = getElementsByIdStartsWith("textarea", "body_content");
for(var i = 0; i < affectedElements.length; i++) {
    affectedElements[i].action = CKEDITOR.replace( /* ... */ );
}
```

However, this is not very efficient and sounds like an XY problem to me. It would be better to avoid this in the first place, for example by tagging the textareas you want to replace with a common class. Then you could simply do

```
var affectedElements = document.getElementsByClassName("common-class");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var updatedString = originalString.replace(/SOMETHING$/g,"whatever");
```

Comment: whatever is not defined. should be something like *.exe on windows file reseach

Comment: How do you want to append something if you don't know what you want to append?

Comment: I want not to append anything. E.g. I have 3 textareas `body_content_1234`, `body_content_test`, `body_content_3if`.
Now every `textarea` which starts with `body_content` should be replaced with CKEDITOR, doesn't matter what comes after

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string should help you then