# Get all elements with similar id array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have elements like this on a html page:

```
<input id="serial[301888][0]" type="hidden" value="51.0100|T2-QQQ" name="serial[301888][0]">
<input id="serial[301888][1]" type="hidden" value="5.0900|T2-WWW" name="serial[301888][1]">
<input id="serial[301888][2]" type="hidden" value="11.1100|T2-XXX" name="serial[301888][2]">
<input id="serial[301888][3]" type="hidden" value="22.5600|T2-YYY" name="serial[301888][3]">
<input id="serial[301888][4]" type="hidden" value="10.2300|T2-ZZZ" name="serial[301888][4]">
```

Without using jQuery, how could I get all these elements into an array?

Comment: Is this want you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can combine JavaScript's [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) with CSS's [`^=` attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="serial[301888]"]');
```

This will generate an array of all elements whose `id` attributes start with `"serial[301888]"`.

Comment: Note that that's definitively *not* an Array (as requested).

Comment: @DavidThomas that is indeed true, but `querySelectorAll` does return an Array-like object. I doubt this wouldn't fulfil OP's requirement of it being an array as jQuery's selectors themselves do not return Array instances either.

Comment: Agreed; my point wasn't that your code wouldn't work, just pointing out that it wouldn't return an array (though, of course, it does return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is, in many ways, very similar). I was aiming for clarity, rather than criticism; but my language choices sometimes fail.