# About getElementById find multiple id name?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three id tag

```
<div id="view_1"></div>
<div id="view_2"></div>
<div id="view_3"></div>
```

I use getElementsByClassName way it can work

but "class" I take it to delimit css style

How could use  document.getElementById find -> "view_1" "view_2" "view_3"

```
    function hideDIV(){

        var divs = document.getElementById('view'.*);
        for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
          divs[i].style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use jquery???

Comment: ID is a unique identifier. Use `querySelectorAll` and use attribute selector like - `alert(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="view_"]').length);`

Comment: @nlstduio what you want actually, can you explain the usecase ?

Comment: thanks a lot , I try explain the usecase , upon I upload a picture , 
when I close A , then B and C are close too .
when I press A , show B , press B show C like this ......

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].id.indexOf('view_') == 0) {
        divs[i].style.display='none';
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtguz233/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use QuerySelectorAll for that:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="view_"]').id;
```

This will get all views that start with `view_`

See:
[Javascript getElementById base on partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string)

Comment: QuerySelector returns only the first element. You want QuerySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/L1vd69s3/)

JS:

```
$('[id*="view"]').hide();
```

Html:

```
<div id="view_1"> dcf</div>
<div id="view_2"> DSg</div>
<div id="view_3"> gsde</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**No, it won't work.**

document.getElementById() method accepts only one argument.

However, you may always set classes to the elements and use `getElementsByClassName()` instead. Another option for modern browsers is to use  `querySelectorAll()`method:

use `$("div[id*='view']")`

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/mkufymqr/1/

Comment: thanks everyone , Excuse me, if I would add variable in here

  function hideDIV(idTag){
   
   $('[id*='+idTag+'"_"]').hide();  

Is this right way ?

Answer (score 0):

[Vanilla JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="view_"]');
```

[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('div[id^="view_"]');
```

[CSS 3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

```
div[id^="view_"] { ... }
```

But consider using classes, not IDs, to semantically target elements.

Eg: search for all DIVs with the `targetDiv` class, and add the `hidden` class to them. Then define the `hidden` class as `display: none` in CSS.