# java script replace for html attributes

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a html tag like the following:

```
            <div id="slide1" class="mySlides" type="slide" index="1" duration="1100" style="display: block;">
                <div id="page_number1" class="numbertext">1/2</div>
                <div id="slide_content1"><p>First Slide</p>
</div>
                <div id="slide_h1" class="slide_h1"></div>
                <div id="slide_h2" class="slide_h2"></div>
                <div id="playOptions{slide_number}" class="playOptions">|
                    <span id="remaining_slide_time{slide_number}"></span> |
                    <span id="remaining_time{slide_number}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need to replace `{slide_number}` with an integer. Whatever I tried the result doesn't replace the `{slide_number}`

```
var str = template.replace("{slide_number}", i);
```

Comment: Possibly a xy problem since using a class what be much easier, very sure bad programming because you [don't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (and replaceAll doesn't exist)

Comment: @chrispbacon so what is the solution!

Comment: So you want to replace this in HTML, not as a string?

Comment: I already said: use a class instead. Apart from that, it's impossible to say; there's not enough code

Comment: @NenadVracar yes in html

Comment: @chrispbacon I don't get what do you mean by using a class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector contains that will select all elements where id contains `{slide_number}` and you can replace that part of the id with the number.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[id*='{slide_number}']").forEach(function(e) {
  e.id = e.id.replace("{slide_number}", 1)
})
```

```html
<div id="slide1" class="mySlides" type="slide" index="1" duration="1100" style="display: block;">
  <div id="page_number1" class="numbertext">1/2</div>
  <div id="slide_content1">
    <p>First Slide</p>
  </div>
  <div id="slide_h1" class="slide_h1"></div>
  <div id="slide_h2" class="slide_h2"></div>
  <div id="playOptions{slide_number}" class="playOptions">|
    <span id="remaining_slide_time{slide_number}"></span> |
    <span id="remaining_time{slide_number}"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can find them  from

> document.querySelector('[id$="{slide_number}"]').id;
>   and 
>   document.querySelector('[id*="{slide_number}"]').id;

[Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string)

Answer (score -1):

**If you use jquery then it can be done like below:**

```
$('#playOptions').attr('id','playOptions88');
```

But I recommend you to use HTML `data` attribute to distinguish different element. It is a very nice thing to work with multiple elements that can be needed to change dynamically.

If you change your ID attribute dynamically adding some integer number then it may be harder to catch them. Instead, use `data` like below code.

You can make any element unique setting the `data-SOMETHING`.

If you write the code below:

`$('#playOptions').data('roll','100');`

Then the element will be

`<div id="playOptions" data-roll="100" class="playOptions">`

If you write the code below:

`$('#playOptions').data('name','ahmad');`

Then the element will be

`<div id="playOptions" data-name="ahmad" class="playOptions">`

You can then catch the element by the code below:

```
var name =  $('#playOptions').data('name');
console.log(name) //Output should be 'ahmad'

Similarly,

var roll = $('#playOptions').data('roll');
console.log(roll) //Output should be '100'
```

To learn more about the `data` attribute please see the link
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked:

```
   var find = '{slide_number}';
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    str = template.replace(re, i);
```