# Using RegEx to match patterns in HTML DOM form labels and IDs

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

I'm having an issue where the team that developed a web based application used a WYSIWYG editor and, a couple months ago, they updated some of the HTML form labels and IDs. My team creates macros that work with the DOM to gather/enter/update information in these web based applications. When I got a report about the update, I looked into it and found that the original code for a specific line was:

```
strQ = objIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblQueue").innerTEXT
```

Whatever is in the label for this element ID would be stored in `strQ` and used to detect the work queue the user is working from in another web based application. When the team for the first application made the update, the code for the label's element ID became:

```
strQ = objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblQueue").innerTEXT
```

As you can see, they removed the `ctl00_` from the beginning of the label' element ID. Just a few days ago, then made another update and it was added back. Since all the label IDs begin with `ContentPlaceHolder1_` and can sometimes contain `ctl00_`, is there any way of using RegExp to simply find `lblQueue` in the label's ID?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Also: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/nov/07/clientidmode-in-aspnet-40

Comment: @wazz So, if I understand you offering both links, I can't use RegExp to locate the label's ID, but I can somehow use ClientIDMode to find it?

Comment: Read the 2nd article. It's a way of adding a setting that permanently gets rid of extra crap in the markup, like `ctl00`. Maybe the developers can include it.

Comment: you might still be able to use regex, not sure. check back for other answers.

Comment: I'm meeting with the developers today, so I may be posting a solution, but I'm trying to get ahead of them on this. They are the ones that suggested using RegEx and offered this as a solution (which I haven't got working): `strQ = objIE.document.getElementById(“\wContentPlaceHolder1_lblQueue”).innerTEXT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the querySelector as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296220/4181058

In your example it would be (id$ means where the ID 'ends with'):

```
document.querySelector('[id$="lblQueue"]').innerText
```

Comment: I've seen examples like this, but they were outdated and I didn't see the one you sent me. Thanks. Now that I understand what they are doing, I'll give this a try and see if it works for me.

Comment: I just updated my code with your suggestion and it worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: It can be used either way. I used it in VBScript: `objIE.Document.getElementById("[id$='txtClaimID']").Value = strICN`.