# Get Full ID from element with token from WebBrowser VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, getelementbyid, queryselector

How can I get the full ID from an element with a token or a numric ID at the end,
Something like this but VB.NET didn't seem to handle the querySelector the same way.

[Javascript getElementById base on partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-base-on-partial-string/24296220)

eg.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for you is:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim wb1 As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser
        Dim resultElements As List(Of HtmlElement) = New List(Of HtmlElement)

        Dim processElement As Action(Of HtmlElement) = Sub(element As HtmlElement)

                                                           Dim elementID As String = element.GetAttribute("id")


                                                           If Len(elementID) > 0 Then
                                                               Console.WriteLine(elementID)
                                                           End If

                                                           'You can change this with your conditions
                                                           If elementID IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                                                           elementID.EndsWith("_01") AndAlso
                                                           resultElements.IndexOf(element) = -1 Then

                                                               resultElements.Add(element)

                                                           End If

                                                           'Or put here other conditions
                                                           'If elementName IsNot Nothing AndAlso elementName.StartsWith("01_ABCD") AndAlso resultElements.IndexOf(element) = -1 Then resultElements.Add(element)


                                                           If element.Children IsNot Nothing AndAlso element.Children.Count > 0 Then

                                                               For Each children In element.Children
                                                                   processElement(children)
                                                               Next

                                                           End If


                                                       End Sub


        AddHandler wb1.DocumentCompleted, Sub(senderWb As Object, eWb As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

                                              Dim allElements = wb1.Document.All

                                              If allElements IsNot Nothing And allElements.Count > 0 Then
                                                  For Each element As HtmlElement In allElements
                                                      processElement(element)
                                                  Next
                                              End If

                                              ' Here You have all your elements with custom ID condition 
                                              If resultElements.Count > 0 Then

                                                  For Each okElement As HtmlElement In resultElements
                                                      Console.WriteLine(okElement.GetAttribute("id"))
                                                  Next

                                              End If

                                          End Sub

        wb1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com")

    End Sub
```

Take me informed  :)