# How to use custom variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to know to how to use custom varible with javascript.suppose we have 5 id with name zawsz,baws2,tawsx,paws4,vawsa and we want to execute single DOM command to all these element whose id is define here.

```
document.getElementById("-aws-").onclick=function(){}
```

Here -aws- define all the id define above.(-) can be replace with any char/int value;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript getElementById based on a partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-based-on-a-partial-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code:
(The following code will select all elements of which the id includes aws.
I have tested this code and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/5042woqz/)

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[id*="aws"]').forEach(function(item) {
    item.onclick=function() {
        console.log('click!');
    };
});
```

Items will now be an array containing all your aws- items.
If you have further questions, just let me know.

P.S.: You could achieve the same thing really easily with jquery.

Comment: i just edit question..please help with that problem.

Comment: I edited it! if I helped you, don't forget to mark the answer as solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="aws"]')
```

That will select all elements where the `id` attribute starts with (`^=`) "aws".

Comment: Updated to use `querySelectorAll`.