# How to assign a value to an array input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm quite new in JavaScript so I'm unsure on some things

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
  <input id="data[$i]" />
}
```

```
document.getElementById("data"[count]).value = "Value";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript getElementById based on a partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-based-on-a-partial-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the correct id when using `document.getElementById`.

Through the html code, the id is set like `data[1]`, `data[2]`, `data[3]` ... so you need to generate that id name.
Instead of `"data"[count]`, you can write as follows to get the id.

```
`data[${i}]`  // Here, i = 1,2,3,4,5...
```

Below is the working snippet.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i ++) {
  document.getElementById(`data[${i}]`).value = "Value";
}
```

```html
<input id="data[1]" />
<input id="data[2]" />
<input id="data[3]" />
<input id="data[4]" />
<input id="data[5]" />
```

Comment: will do so when the time restrictions is lifted