# WTForms & getElementById() undefined

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms

Using WTForms and JS I'm trying to create a form that allows the user to add fields to it dynamically on the front end.
I followed this post to get a basic idea of what to do.

https://sagarkaurav.hashnode.dev/flask-wtf-forms-dynamic-fields-using-javascript

I'm now struggling to fetch the input field by id and creating unique ids for the newly generated input fields.

When i execute the script on the front end `document.getElementById('items-item')` returns undefined while `identifyElement.getElementsByTagName('input')` returns the correct amount of fields (1).
Execution of the code is then stopped.
The unedfined points me in the direction that html document isn't created yet upon code execution.
I wrote a similar JS script with window.onload to tackle this, but it deliveres the exact same result and currently I don't understand why and what I'm missing here.

app.py

```python
class purchaseOrderFormSubClass(FlaskForm):
    item = FieldList(StringField(''), min_entries=1, max_entries=99)
    complete = FieldList(BooleanField(''), min_entries=1, max_entries=99)
    ovp = FieldList(BooleanField(''), min_entries=1, max_entries=99)
    instructions = FieldList(BooleanField(''), min_entries=1, max_entries=99)

class purchaseOrderForm(FlaskForm):
    purchaseDate = DateField('Purchase Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
    items = FormField(purchaseOrderFormSubClass)

@app.route('/create_purchase_order')
def create_purchase_order():
    PurchaseOrderForm  = purchaseOrderForm()
    if PurchaseOrderForm.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('create_purchase_order.html', form=PurchaseOrderForm)
    return render_template('create_purchase_order.html', form=PurchaseOrderForm)
```

Template for create_purchase_order.html

```html
    <div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      {{form.purchaseDate.label}}
      {{ form.purchaseDate(class_="form-control") }} <br>
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">TH1</th>
              <th scope="col">TH2</th>
              <th scope="col">TH3</th>
              <th scope="col">TH4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableBody">
          <tr>
            {% for field in form.items%}
            <td>
              {{ field.hidden_tag }}
              {{ field(class_='form-control') }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="add-row" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">New Row onload</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow()">New Row onclick</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

EDIT

rendered HTML

```html
 <div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImU2NzVjZTY5ZWJlMDRlMzQzZmEwZWZlMjg4MTk5Y2RmMWNmOTFiMDIi.ZfDXXQ.NJc4fzGNyipMe5kyPuFhKk3zoss">
      <label for="purchaseDate">Purchase Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="purchaseDate" name="purchaseDate" required type="date" value=""> <br>
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">TH1</th>
              <th scope="col">TH2</th>
              <th scope="col">TH3</th>
              <th scope="col">TH4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableBody">
          <tr scope="row" class="align-middle">
            
            <td>
              <ul class="form-control" id="items-item"><li><label for="items-item-0"></label> <input id="items-item-0" name="items-item-0" type="text" value=""></li></ul>
            </td>
            
            <td>
              <ul class="form-control" id="items-complete"><li><label for="items-complete-0"></label> <input id="items-complete-0" name="items-complete-0" type="checkbox" value="y"></li></ul>
            </td>
            
            <td>
              <ul class="form-control" id="items-ovp"><li><label for="items-ovp-0"></label> <input id="items-ovp-0" name="items-ovp-0" type="checkbox" value="y"></li></ul>
            </td>
            
            <td>
              <ul class="form-control" id="items-instructions"><li><label for="items-instructions-0"></label> <input id="items-instructions-0" name="items-instructions-0" type="checkbox" value="y"></li></ul>
            </td>
            
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" id="items-csrf_token" name="items-csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImU2NzVjZTY5ZWJlMDRlMzQzZmEwZWZlMjg4MTk5Y2RmMWNmOTFiMDIi.ZfDXXQ.NJc4fzGNyipMe5kyPuFhKk3zoss">
            </td>
            
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <button id="add-row" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">New Row onload</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow()">New Row onclick</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

JS

```js
      function addRow() {
                  alert('clicked');
                  let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
                  let identifyElement = document.getElementById('items-item');
                  let countAllElements = identifyElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
                  let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
                  let identifyElementAlert = identifyElement.value;
                  let countAllElementsAlert = countAllElements.length;
                  alert(identifyElementAlert);
                  alert(countAllElementsAlert);
                  let newElementID = []
                            for(let i = 0; i = countAllElements.length; i++) {
                              newElementID.push(parseInt(countAllElements[i].name.split('-')[1]));
                            }
                            let newFieldName = `items-item${Math.max(...newElementID) + 1}`;
                  alert(newElementID);
                  alert(newFieldName);
                  newRow.innerHTML= `
                  <td>
                    <label for="${newFieldName}"></label> <input id="${newFieldName}" name="${newFieldName}" type="text" value="" class="form-control">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label for="items-complete-0"></label> <input id="items-complete-0" name="items-complete-0" type="checkbox" value="y">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label for="items-ovp-0"></label> <input id="items-ovp-0" name="items-ovp-0" type="checkbox" value="y">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label for="items-instructions-0"></label> <input id="items-instructions-0" name="items-instructions-0" type="checkbox" value="y">
                  </td>
                  `;
                  tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
      }
```

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that one of your inputs should have id="items-item"? Which input? I'm not seeing anything with that ID.

Comment: Yes, the input is rendered using WTForms inside this block `{% for field in form.items%}
            <td>
              {{ field.hidden_tag }}
              {{ field(class_='form-control') }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}`
The actual id of the input field is 'items-item-0' then, which returns nothing if called by `document.getElementById('items-item-0')` the code get's executed though, with an additional row appended to the body of the table and 'items-item-Infinity' as it's id.

Comment: You should include the rendered html. And perhaps this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991494/javascript-getelementbyid-based-on-a-partial-string

Comment: Thanks for your effort, while I still don't really know why my code didn't work, the direction in which you pointed is what Detlef used to create a new solution. Your suggestion is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your for loop. Instead of comparing, you assign a new value to `i`. Because of this, the current element can no longer be found and `undefined` is returned.

Here is an alternative version to your code.

```js
function addRow() {
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="items-item-"]');
    if (elems.length) {
        const elem = elems[elems.length-1], 
                tr0 = elem.closest('tr'), 
                tr1 = tr0.cloneNode(true)
        Array.from(tr1.querySelectorAll('label[for^="items-"]')).forEach(label => {
            const attr = label.getAttribute('for'), 
                    input = tr1.querySelector(`input[name="${attr}"]`), 
                    s = attr.replace(/items-(\w+)-(\d+)/, (match, p1, p2) => `items-${p1}-${parseInt(p2)+1}`); 
            label.setAttribute('for', s);
            input.id = input.name = s;
        })
        tr0.parentNode.insertBefore(tr1, tr0.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your script is working properly and returns the expected result. Still i'd like to understand why my solution isn't working. In my for loop i don't want to compare values but count the elements (ids with items-item and input tag) and +1 to determine the correct value for the new id & label. But my code fails before as it can't identify the elements prperly.
Anyway, thank you again for your solution and showing me a different approach that takes less code and is way more robust for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you intend to iterate over all elements with the for loop. So both the initialization `let i=0;` and the incrementation `i++` are correct. However, the termination condition is an assignment. I think you wanted to write something like `i < countAllElements.length;`. But you wrote `i = countElements.length` and so `i` takes the value of `countElements.length` and gets out of bounds.